# Issue with iOS Localization - NSLocalizedString

Tags: ios, localization

I have an issue with NSLocalizedString, I try to translate the text below which is located in one of the tab bar icons, but what only appears is `Text_to` even after giving the equivalent in the other language in `infoPlist.Strings` (file)

My code :

> ```
> [[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Text_to", nil)];
> ```

infoPlist.Strings (file) :

> "Text_to" = "translated text is here";

Just for the info, I am working under xCode 5.0.2 and iOS7

Any ideas on how to solve it ?

Comment: `InfoPlist.strings` is for localizing values in your app's `Info.plist` file, hence the name. `NSLocalizedString()` uses a `Localizable.strings` file. Note that while the default project templates often include a `InfoPlist.strings` file for you, they don't include a `Localizable.strings`; you'll need to create it yourself, possibly using the `genstrings` tool. See `man genstrings` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it into the file Localizable.strings instead of infoPlist.Strings.

Comment: I don't have `Localizable.strings` file, anyway I've created it. But, the same issue, nothing changed, by the way I have 2 languages it may because of that ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to localise your strings you should add the to ***Localizable.strings*** file corresponding to the language you would like to translate. 
Here is a quick overview from Apple about how to do it [Localising Strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000005-SW1) and also a tutorial to create a new strings file for your target language [Creating string files](http://www.stephenbalaban.com/babatuba-ios-internationalization/)

You must be sure your project has internationalisation on:
[image: iOS7 Internationalisation enabled]

In your project navigation inspect if you've already create a strings files for your target language:
[image: Strings files in project]

Comment: I am still stuck with, it does wanna change :s

Comment: Please, just to check add the following lines before your code to check that the view controller and the translated text are ok:      NSAssert([self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0], @"view controller should not be nil");
    NSAssert(NSLocalizedString(@"Text_to", nil), @"Translation should not be nil");

Comment: When I add the line, the icon and its title disappear.